# Norm equivalent with supremum norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider functional $$\|f\| := \sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(q_n)|2^{-n}$$ for $f \in C([-1, 1])$ and $(q_n)$ is a sequence of rational numbers in $[-1, 1]$ i.e.  $\mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1] = \{q_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I want to prove that this norm is not equivalent with supremum norm. It's obvious that

$$\exists_{C>0}:\|f\| \le C\|f\|_\infty$$
We just need to take $C = 1$ (it's because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n} = 1$).
However I want to find counterexample of second inequality i.e. I want to prove that

$$\forall_{c>0}\exists_{f \in C([-1, 1])}: \|f\| < c \cdot \|f\|_\infty$$

I'm not sure which exactly $f$ should I pick. I was trying to pick $f(q_n) = q_n$, $f(q_n) = \frac c 2$, $f(q_n) = \frac c 2 + 1$ but each one of them is not suitable for our problem. Do I have good intuition that this inequality does not hold?

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if I understood correctly or I do something wrong but if we fix some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and define $f(q_n) = 1$ for $n \le n_0$ and $f(q_n) = 0$ for $n >n_0$, we obtain:

$$\|f\| = \sum_{n=1}^{n_0} 2^{-n}  = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac{1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n_0}}{1 - \frac 1 2} = 1 - (\frac 1 2)^{n_0}$$ And now $\|f\| < c \cdot \|f\|_\infty$ is in form $$1 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n_0} < c$$

which is not true for any $c>0$. Where is mistake in my justification?

Answer (score 3):

For the other direction, choose $f$ such that $f(q_n)=1$ and $f(q_i)=0$ for all $i<n$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n$ there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$, $f(x)=1$ for some $x$ and $f(q_i)=0$ for $ 1\leq i \leq n$. Note that $\|f\| \leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac  1 {2^{k}}$. Can you finish?